# File name error when trying to create a file

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a file with the following code

```
testnum= '01'
file_name = 'output\test'+ testnum +'.txt'
with open(file_name,'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('Hallo')
```

but I got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-322cc04151aa> in <module>()
      1 testnum= '01'
      2 file_name = 'output\test'+ testnum +'.txt'
----> 3 with open(file_name,'w') as file:
      4     file.write('Hallo')

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'output\test01.txt'
```

I am using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Use `r'output\test'` or `'output\\test'`. A backslash is an escape character, so `'\t'` indicates a TAB character, which is not what you mean in your filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` is the tab character.  You need to escape the `\` by doubling it in order to get an actual `\` literal:

```
testnum= '01'
file_name = 'output\\test'+ testnum +'.txt'
# Here -------------^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked now